# Laravel switch between Queue and not Queue

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

how do you switch between ShouldQueue and Sync in a class?

We have got an endpoint which accepts an argument whether a job should be fired immediately or later.

In both cases the same logic should be executed but in one scenario I expect and answer back and the other one should be handled async.

I am aware of implementing "ShouldQueue" and use the "InteractsWithQueue"-Trait but how can we use this in one situation and not use it in the other?

Can you programatically set whether a request should be queued or not or are there better ways to do this? Thanks

Comment: Haven't tested this yet myself, but can you instantiate the job class and if it must be run immediately, or "online", then just call the `handle()` method in your controller? If you want to run it in the queue, or "offline", you can use the dispatcher to queue it like normal.

Comment: @xjstratedgebx yes, this works but how do I pass in a variable in both cases? In the dispatch case it is expected in the constructor, in the handle case the handle method.

Comment: If you resolve the job class through the service container (i.e. `$job = app(\App\Jobs\MyJob::class);`), any classes you type hint in the constructor will automatically be passed for you. If you call `handle()` manually and it requires you to pass parameters, then just pass the parameters when you call it. No need to worry about those parameters when you queue it - I believe the service container will automatically inject the parameters when its run from the queue.

Comment: @xjstratedgebx - Thank you for your effort. Joseph Silber down here had a better solution. But that one should work also.

Comment: Not a problem, his solution is good for me to know as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller:

```php
$this->dispatch($job) // queued if implements ShouldQueue

$this->dispatchNow($job) // never queues
```

---

If stuck on Laravel 5.1, create a new instance of the `Dispatcher` yourself:

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher;

// Later ...

app(Dispatcher::class)->dispatchNow($job);
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, this was to good to be true. dispatchNow is not a function. Do I need anything else for this to work?

Comment: @hogan which version of Laravel are you using? It's in 5.2 at least (see [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/DispatchesJobs.html#method_dispatchNow)). All it does is app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher::class)->dispatchNow($job);

Comment: @hogan - if you've upgraded from an earlier version of Laravel, be sure to use the `Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/DispatchesJobs` trait in your controller.

Comment: Oh, should have mentioned it's Laravel 5.1

Comment: @JosephSilber - Thank you for your answer and effort! It works as described.